# How to explain the following Plot behaviour. PlotRange effect

Tags: plotting

Could someone please explain the following result.

```
ClearAll[x, t];
x[t_] := -UnitStep[t + 2] + Ramp[t + 2] - Ramp[t + 1] + 
   UnitStep[t + 1] + UnitStep[t] - UnitStep[t - 1] - Ramp[t - 1] + Ramp[t - 2];
```

And now

```
Plot[x[2 t + 1], {t, -3, 6}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

Which gives expected output

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now see what happens when the option `PlotRange -> All` is removed

```
Plot[x[2 t + 1], {t, -3, 6}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Btw, the `Exclusions -> None` has no effect. Same thing will happen if it is used or not. It seems Mathematica could not figure the real plot range in the `y` axis in the second case. But why is that? May be problem with how `Plot` did sampling here? but why?

Is this a known issue or do you think it is a bug?

V 12 on windows 10.

Comment: It might be a bug indeed. Note that the `Piecewise[]` expression generated by `Simplify[x[2 t + 1]]` plots just fine. The equivalent expression `-(1 + 2 t) UnitStep[2 t] + (-1 + 2 t) UnitStep[-1 + 2 t] + UnitStep[1 + 2 t] - (1 + 2 t) UnitStep[2 + 2 t] + 2 (1 + t) UnitStep[3 + 2 t]` also has that `PlotRange` problem.

Comment: The `Automatic` setting for `PlotRange` does not mean `All` (or `All` except in the case of asymptotes). It means find the most interesting plot range. At least that's how it seems to me. In this case, the heuristic finds a quite interesting one showing the effects of subtracting floating-point numbers that have a 1 ulp error wjen `t` is near `2^k-1`. Unfortunately, it is not a plot range that most users would desire for this plot. If you run statistics on the plotted points, you'll find it did indeed capture most of the plotted points and shows a lot of variation.

Comment: It's a borderline case for the heuristics, as can be shown by changing the upper `t` limit to `5` or `8`. (But `{t, -3, 7}` still homes in on the round-off jitter, including the jitter near `t = 7`.)  The full plot will be shown if the option `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` is used instead of `PlotRange`. It eliminates the jitter, and the zoomed-in plot is no longer as interesting as the full plot.

Comment: Increasing the `PlotPoints`, e.g., `Plot[x[2 t + 1], {t, -3, 6}, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]` causes the automatic selection of the range to show the full plot.